# Problem: Rendering from command line longer than rendering from Blender GUI?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, command-line

Can someone please explain why command line render took almost twice as longer when it was supposed to be faster then a render via GUI? I am confused, everyone's talking about how command render is much faster. What am I missing here? Tested it a couple of times, CL was always longer.
Tested with the same file, no changes in any settings.

```
Blender 3.6.4 on GTX 1080 Ti 12gb, i5 7400, 16gb ram. Win 11. Cycles CUDA. 
Command used: "D:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\blender.exe" -b "C:\Users\Vuk\Downloads\barbershop_interior.blend" -f 1 -- --cycles-device CUDA
```

[image]

Comment: Your memory peaks are very different, so there must be a difference in the settings when rendering per UI vs CLI. Start checking by looking into `Edit > Preferences > System > Cycles Render Device`.